# asp.net control to expand textbox?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, textbox

I'm not sure what this functionality is properly called.  But I have a single-line text box in an asp.net gridview.  When a user clicks on that textbox, I want a larger, multi-line textbox to pop-up, so they can see the entire contents and edit it.  This expanded view would go away once the focus moves to another control.

Is there a control out there that allows for this?  If not, how could I go about implementing one?

EDIT:  I'm looking for similar function to how the TextBoxCalendar Extender works, but instead of a calendar, I'd like a multiline textbox to pop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](http://blakepell.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/asp-net-elastic-textbox-with-jquery/) has an elastic textbox that uses jQuery. According to the author,

> ...when the TextBox gets the focus, it will expand to a specified height and width and then when it loses focus it will contract back to it’s more compact size.

Comment: The blog is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look at using javascript/jquery if you want to do this without a postback (which I would recommend).

The link below goes over a good method for doing this:

- http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=175514

Here is the function they call:

```
   function expand(width,height)
    {

    document.getElementById("text_output").cols = width;
    document.getElementById("text_output").rows = height;

    }
```

There may also be a control in the .net AJAX tool kit that does this, but the javascript route would probably be simpler.

UPDATE:

If you are looking for popup functionality then I would definately go the jQuery route. Typically they will have you specify a div that you would like to have popup on a certain event.  The link below gives you a number of modal popup plugins that you can look at using:

- http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not seeing the big picture here...  Wouldn't this push all the page content down under the textbox?  And how could I ever put it back to the exact same size afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the popup requirement.  I would definitely look for a jQuery solution in this case.  See my update for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about an asp.net Textbox you can specify the number of rows like so:

```
    <asp:TextBox id="tb6" rows="5" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" />
```

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_textbox.asp) for more info

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a textbox control, and add an onclick Event handler that changes the "rows" property to something greater than 1, thus multi-line.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Plus, asp.net textbox doesn't have an onclick event.